# Solve $2x(1+\frac{1}{x^3})+7(1+\frac{1}{x})=0$ without cubic formulas and such

Tags: quadratics

Just like in the title, I wonder if there is a way to solve $2x(1+\frac{1}{x^3})+7(1+\frac{1}{x})=0$ without any use of solving cubics including the rational root theorem (with these methods I already got $x=-2,-1,-\frac{1}{2}$).

The original equation is supposed to be related to quadratic substitution (the ones where you do $t=x^2$, like $x^4-2x^2+1=0$).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

$$2x\left( 1+\frac { 1 }{ x^{ 3 } }  \right) +7\left( 1+\frac { 1 }{ x }  \right) =0\\ \left( 1+\frac { 1 }{ x }  \right) \left( 2x\left( 1-\frac { 1 }{ x } +\frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } }  \right) +7 \right) =0\\ \left( 1+\frac { 1 }{ x }  \right) \left( 2x+5+\frac { 2 }{ { x } }  \right) =0\\ 1+\frac { 1 }{ x } =0\Rightarrow x+1=0\Rightarrow x=-1\\ 2x+5+\frac { 2 }{ { x } } =0\\ 2{ x }^{ 2 }+5x+2=0\\ x=\frac { -5\pm 3 }{ 4 } \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ $$

Comment: Ha-ha! But in this way you have used "formulas and such"!

Comment: @guestDiego,what do you mean by ""formulas and such"?

Comment: By "cubic formulas and such" I meant the trippy formulas for the solutions of the cubic. I explained more in the thread itself.

Comment: @haqnatural This should be a question for Theoniix. it was just a joke